# Validate incoming requests

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-analytics

Just recently I was wondering, how Google manages it with analytics to track the user but avoid any fraud (as kinda everyone could insert that JS into an HTML page).

Can anyone tell me, if they just resolve the Domain on each incoming request and validate if it corresponds to the correct account and comes from a allowed server (by looking up the IP)? If that's not the case, can anyone provide me some Idea on how Google could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not, by and large, avoid fraud at all. They offer an option to automatically filter for known bots and spiders, and apparently they intervened in some fashion against [referral spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam) (which used to be a huge problem but has by now almost completely disappeared at least from the accounts I have access to).

Other than that, as you say, anyone can stick the javascript code into his HTML and send data to your account, or use the measurement protocol and not even bother with JS. Checking server IPs would hardly help (relevant here is the IP of the client and there are too many possible IPs for meaningful filtering).

Of course if you notice wrong data that follows a discernible pattern you can create filters yourself, which is at least gives you some control over what data is removed.